# how to hide/show html tag in type script in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, show-hide

I have created a form in angular Html component, which is used to add users and update them using dialog module.
If the user clicks for updating, I want to hide password input in HTML.

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="password" matInput/>  
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf='!isUpdating'>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Mot de passe</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="password" matInput/>  
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
export class Component {
    isUpdating = false;

    onUpdate() {
        this.isUpdating = true;
    }
}
```

You can add condition on Password Input Whenever **isUpdating** will set to true then password input will removed from DOM and If **isUpdating** will set to false then Password input will add in DOM automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` directive to show/hide content. Basically, it accepts an expression. When the expression evaluates to `true` it shows the DOM, otherwise, it removes it from DOM. Over here you can control the behavior using `isUpdating` boolean.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="isUpdating">
    <mat-label>Mot de passe</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="password" matInput/>  
</mat-form-field>
```

---

I feel that for this use case, rather than hiding the field. You can disable the field until it is updating the `password` field. By show/hide field would introduce a flicker effect on UI (and that would be annoying for user)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="isUpdating">
    <mat-label>Mot de passe</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="password" matInput [disabled]="isUpdating"/>  
</mat-form-field>
```

After disabling the field. You can not retrieve `password` field from `FormGroup` object. You can get that using `form.getRawValue()` method instead of `form.value` method.

Comment: Thanks that work, but when I update the user, I get this error :  PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/adminupdate/41 422 (Unprocessable Content) , in the backend I have put the password required, when I update the user I don't want the update her password. Have you any idea?

Comment: check edit, you should use `form.getRawValue()` instead of `form.value` –

Comment: Hello, does it work for you?

Comment: when I have tested form.getRawValue() it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide me a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k2fgps?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftech-dialog%2Ftech-dialog.component.ts

Comment: @Dev the given stackblitz isn't functioning

Comment: @Dev hello, any luck to reproduce the problem in stackblitz?

Comment: Hello sir, normally I have tested the link, anyways I have changed something in my form and now it works,  thank you so much for the help.